# Cordova plugin installation is not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to install this plugin:

https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-playerhater

So I execute this command

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-playerhater.git
```

And add this to config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.nypr.cordova.playerhaterplugin" version="0.1.0" />
```

After that I try:

```
alert(window.audioplayer); //undefined
alert(window.cordova.plugins); //{"fileextras":{}, "barcodeScanner":{...}}
alert(window.cordova.plugins.audioplayer); //undefined
```

How do I make this plugin work ?

Comment: I had face similar issue. After installtion of plugin , I have fired cordova build android command then I get accessed of plugin.

Comment: on what platform are you trying to use this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the command is :

```
cordova local plugin add https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-playerhater.git
```

hence it didnt added pulgin properly , i would suggest you to do follow thing to install pulgin and do not add any code in config.xml manually .

1. Download this plugin zip from [here](https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-playerhater.git)
2. run command as : cordova plugin add [path of the extracted folder on
   ur local machine]
3. Now check you plugin folder and cordova-pulgin.xml the pulgin would
   be added properly

Comment: Cordova does not know local; try `cordova help` for a list of all the available commands.

Comment: Yes  1) I downloaded and extracted zip  2) cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-playerhater-master which gave output: "Plugin "org.nypr.cordova.playerhaterplugin" already installed on android." so I did cordova plugin remove .. and then again installed it: "Plugin "org.nypr.cordova.playerhaterplugin" already installed on android." In plugins folder there's org.nypr.cordova.playerhaterplugin with plugin.xml However in javascript window.audioplayer is undefined..

Comment: is window.audioplayer called on deviceReady?

Comment: sorry <> didnt came in post u need to add path locally remove it and chk if it exist in pulgin folder

Comment: "Is window.audioplayer called on deviceReady?" - yes. It's undefined and window.cordova.plugins returns only {"fileextras":{}, "barcodeScanner":{...}}, no audioPlayer